# How can I extract an array from a two-dimensional array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I have once again forgotten how to get `$_` to represent an array when it is in a loop of a two dimensional array.

```
foreach(@TWO_DIM_ARRAY){
   my @ARRAY = $_;
}
```

That's the intention, but that doesn't work.  What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you show the data you are starting with and what you want to end up with, even if in pseudocode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `my @ARRAY = @$_;` (instead of `= $_;`) is what you're looking for, but unless you explicitly want to make a copy of the referenced array, I would use @$_ directly.

Well, actually I wouldn't use `$_` at all, especially since you're likely to want to iterate through `@$_`, and then you use implicit `$_` in the inner loop too, and then you could have a mess figuring out which `$_` is which, or if that's even legal.  Which may have been why you were copying into @ARRAY in the first place.

Anyway, here's what I would do:

```
for my $array_ref (@TWO_DIM_ARRAY) {

    # You can iterate through the array:
    for my $element (@$array_ref) {
        # do whatever to $element
    }

    # Or you can access the array directly using arrow notation:
    $array_ref->[0] = 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the for my $var syntax. Seems like a lot of people don't bother with this, though it improves readability quite a lot.

Comment: Still, why doesn't this work: foreach(@TWO_DIM_ARRAY){ print join ',',@{$_}; }   After all, $_ is an array reference, and @{$_} should be an array.

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn: That will work too.  `@{$_}` is the same as `@$_`.   For example, I just tried this: `my @A=([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]); foreach(@A) { print join(",", @{$_}), "\n"; }`

Answer (score 4):

```
for (@TWO_DIM_ARRAY) {
    my @arr = @$_;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `$_` will be array *references* (not *arrays*), so you need to dereference it as:

```
my @ARRAY = @$_;
```